# Silverlight DomainService not returning information from include()

Tags: linq, silverlight-4.0, ria, iqueryable, domainservices

I have two queries in my RIA DomainService.  one is a simple get using linq and the other is a get with a peramiter and a linq join.  the simple get when using include() returns the data i want to my silverlight datagrid.  the one with the join does not, why?

here are my two methods.  the top one is the one that works.

```
    public IQueryable<UserProfile> GetUserProfiles()
    {
        // GetUserProfiles order by sum of carma
        return from up in ObjectContext.UserProfiles.Include("PriceRange")
               where up.Active
               orderby up.SumKarma descending 
               select up;
    }

    public IQueryable<UserProfile> GetUserProfilesByCountyID(int searchCountyID)
    {
        return from up in ObjectContext.UserProfiles.Include("PriceRange")
               join upsc in ObjectContext.UserProfileSearchCounties on up.IDUserProfile equals upsc.IDUserProfile
               where up.Active && upsc.IDSearchCounty == searchCountyID
               orderby up.SumKarma descending
               select up;

    }
```

UPDATE: with comment from Cubicle.Jockey i was able to work through this.  below is what i ended up using.

```
    public IEnumerable<UserProfileSearchCounty> GetUserProfilesByCountyID(int searchCountyID)
    {
        return (from upsc in ObjectContext.UserProfileSearchCounties.Include("UserProfile").Include("UserProfile.PriceRange")
                where upsc.UserProfile.Active && upsc.IDSearchCounty == searchCountyID
                orderby upsc.UserProfile.SumKarma descending
                select upsc).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the data is not being returned because you are doing a select on up which is just UserProfile and not the joined query you were performing.